# Piping large data in PHP makes stdin empty, are any options which can be tweaked/increased?

Tags: php, stdin

I was trying to read the stdin in a php-cli script invoked from another program. Works fine for files up to 70-80MB, but after that the stdin returns EOF and is empty.

So the question is: if are any limits in php.ini or maybe filesystem(but I dobt, for C programs works fine) which can affect this stdin? Or is a bug in PHP?

Comment: are you taking full file in memory or processing line by line

Comment: Tried all methods, there is no data comming from STDIN at all, just  EOF after few seconds. PHP does not give any error, nothing. Just an empty STDIN and EOF in few seconds.

Comment: The cli is called by a execv from the parent. Reading in normal way with a cat test|php asdf.php works fine.

Comment: My question remain same are you taking full file in memory or processing it line by line

Comment: If there is no data comming from STDIN... I tried fread/fgets/stream_get_contents, stream_ set_ blocking 0/1, stream_set_timeout etc. I'm not getting any character at all, just an EOF after 10 seconds. (and only when file is over 80MB or so...)

Comment: And to be more precise, is about the STDIN from a network connection. The local one works fine. So must be probably a timeout/limit on the linux system which blocks the ammount of incoming data/session

Comment: After more testing looks like is the Outlook or Windows which was sending the email. Using netcat worked fine... Will look more into it, because could not find the solution on internet

Comment: And yes The bat can send the emails just fine. Outlook 2003 not. Tested with emails with attachment over 80mb.